# Application becomes terribly slow on full screen - AIR

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I have many movieclips with a sequence of bitmaps inside them, one in each frame. When I set the program to fullscreen or make it bigger on the screen, it gets REALLY slow.

Is this a known problem? Is there some way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the problem already. It isn't related to being in full-screen or not. It happened because I forgot to tell the app to remove some instances after some time, they was still on screen when I added another big object upon the smaller ones, making them invisible but still processor costly.

Comment: Lucas, I think it is better, more in line with how SO is intended to be used, if you would delete this question, rather than answering it your self.